# predict() R function caret package errors: "newdata" rows different, "type" not accepted

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, r-caret, training-data

- I am running a logistic regression analysis using the caret package.
- Data is input as a 18x6 matrix
- everything is fine so far except the `predict()` function.
- R is telling me the `type` parameter is supposed to be `raw` or `prob` but `raw` just spits out an exact copy of the last column (the values of the binomial variable). `prob` gives me the following error:

> "Error in dimnames(out)[[2]] <- modelFit$obsLevels : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   'newdata' had 7 rows but variables found have 18 rows"

```
install.packages("pbkrtest")
install.packages("caret")
install.packages('e1071', dependencies=TRUE)
#install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
require(caret)
library(caret)

A=matrix(
  c(
    64830,18213,4677,24761,9845,17504,22137,12531,5842,28827,51840,4079,1000,2069,969,9173,11646,946,66161,18852,5581,27219,10159,17527,23402,11409,8115,31425,55993,0,0,1890,1430,7873,12779,627,68426,18274,5513,25687,10971,14104,19604,13438,6011,30055,57242,0,0,2190,1509,8434,10492,755,69716,18366,5735,26556,11733,16605,20644,15516,5750,31116,64330,0,0,1850,1679,9233,12000,500,73128,18906,5759,28555,11951,19810,22086,17425,6152,28469,72020,0,0,1400,1750,8599,12000,500,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
  ),

  nrow = 18,
  ncol = 6,
  byrow = FALSE)  #"bycol" does NOT exist
################### data set as vectors
a<-c(64830,18213,4677,24761,9845,17504,22137,12531,5842,28827,51840,4079,1000,2069,969,9173,11646,946)
b<-c(66161,18852,5581,27219,10159,17527,23402,11409,8115,31425,55993,0,0,1890,1430,7873,12779,627)
c<-c(68426,18274,5513,25687,10971,14104,19604,13438,6011,30055,57242,0,0,2190,1509,8434,10492,755)
d<-c(69716,18366,5735,26556,11733,16605,20644,15516,5750,31116,64330,0,0,1850,1679,9233,12000,500)
e<-c(73128,18906,5759,28555,11951,19810,22086,17425,6152,28469,72020,0,0,1400,1750,8599,12000,500)
f<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
######################

n<-nrow(A);
K<-ncol(A)-1;

Train <- createDataPartition(f, p=0.6, list=FALSE)  #60% of data set is used as training.
training <- A[ Train, ]
testing <- A[ -Train, ]
nrow(training)

#this is the logistic formula:
#estimates from logistic regression characterize the relationship between the predictor and response variable on a log-odds scale
mod_fit <- train(f ~ a + b + c + d +e,  data=training, method="glm", family="binomial")
mod_fit

#this isthe exponential function to calculate the odds ratios for each preditor:
exp(coef(mod_fit$finalModel))

predict(mod_fit, newdata=training)
predict(mod_fit, newdata=testing, type="prob")
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to define both A data frame and the a~f vectors?

Comment: @zyurnaidi I did that because I was comparing the binomial variable to the other columns (f vs a-e). I didn't know of any other way to run the logistic formula. Is there a better way?

Comment: Sure, we only need to set up the data as data frame, then access each column by its name. See the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure to understand, but A is a matrix of (a,b,c,d,e,f). So you don't need to create two objects.

```
install.packages("pbkrtest")
install.packages("caret")
install.packages('e1071', dependencies=TRUE)
#install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
require(caret)
library(caret)

A=matrix(
  c(
        64830,18213,4677,24761,9845,17504,22137,12531,5842,28827,51840,4079,1000,2069,969,9173,11646,946,66161,18852,5581,27219,10159,17527,23402,11409,8115,31425,55993,0,0,1890,1430,7873,12779,627,68426,18274,5513,25687,10971,14104,19604,13438,6011,30055,57242,0,0,2190,1509,8434,10492,755,69716,18366,5735,26556,11733,16605,20644,15516,5750,31116,64330,0,0,1850,1679,9233,12000,500,73128,18906,5759,28555,11951,19810,22086,17425,6152,28469,72020,0,0,1400,1750,8599,12000,500,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
  ),
  nrow = 18,
  ncol = 6,
  byrow = FALSE)  #"bycol" does NOT exist

A <- data.frame(A)
colnames(A) <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
A$f <- as.factor(A$f)

Train <- createDataPartition(A$f, p=0.6, list=FALSE)  #60% of data set is used as training.
training <- A[ Train, ]
testing <- A[ -Train, ]
nrow(training)
```

And to predict a variable you must enter the explanatory variables and not the variable to predict

```
mod_fit <- train(f ~ a + b + c + d +e,  data=training, method="glm", family="binomial")
mod_fit

#this isthe exponential function to calculate the odds ratios for each preditor:
exp(coef(mod_fit$finalModel))

predict(mod_fit, newdata=training[,-which(colnames(training)=="f")])
predict(mod_fit, newdata=testing[,-which(colnames(testing)=="f")])
```

Comment: f needs to be a factor, you are trying for a logistic regression. See the `warnings()` being generated. `train(as.factor(f) ~ ., data = training , method = "glm", family = "binomial"`

Comment: Yes it's true, but it's just a warnings, predictions are the same. I correct.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you should not include the explained variable, which is `f` in your `predict` equation. So you should do:

```
predict(mod_fit, newdata=training[, -ncol(training])
predict(mod_fit, newdata=testing[, -ncol(testing])
```

The issue with the warning message `'newdata' had 11 rows but variables found have 18 rows` is because you run the regression using the whole data set (18 observations), but predict using just part of it (either 11 or 7).

**EDIT**: To simplify the data creation and `glm` processes we can do:

```
library(caret)
A <- data.frame(a = c(64830,18213,4677,24761,9845,17504,22137,12531,5842,28827,51840,4079,1000,2069,969,9173,11646,946),
                b = c(66161,18852,5581,27219,10159,17527,23402,11409,8115,31425,55993,0,0,1890,1430,7873,12779,627),
                c = c(68426,18274,5513,25687,10971,14104,19604,13438,6011,30055,57242,0,0,2190,1509,8434,10492,755),
                d = c(69716,18366,5735,26556,11733,16605,20644,15516,5750,31116,64330,0,0,1850,1679,9233,12000,500),
                e = c(73128,18906,5759,28555,11951,19810,22086,17425,6152,28469,72020,0,0,1400,1750,8599,12000,500),
                f = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

Train <- createDataPartition(f, p=0.6, list=FALSE)  #60% of data set is used as training.
training <- A[ Train, ]
testing <- A[ -Train, ]

mod_fit <- train(f ~ a + b + c + d + e,  data=training, method="glm", family="binomial")
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to run logistic regression model. I wrote this code:

```
install.packages('caret')
library(caret)
setwd('C:\\Users\\BAHOZ\\Documents\\')
D<-read.csv(file = "D.csv",header = T)
D<-read.csv(file = 'DataSet.csv',header=T)
names(D)
set.seed(111134)
Train<-createDataPartition(D$X, p=0.7,list = FALSE)
training<-D[Train,]
length(training$age)
testing<-D[-Train,]
length(testing$age)
mod_fit<-train(X~age + gender  + total.Bilirubin + direct.Bilirubin + total.proteins + albumin + A.G.ratio+SGPT + SGOT + Alkphos,data=training,method="glm", family="binomial")
summary(mod_fit)
exp(coef(mod_fit$finalModel))
```

And I recived this message for last command:

```
     (Intercept)              age           gender  total.Bilirubin direct.Bilirubin   total.proteins          albumin        A.G.ratio 
  0.01475027       1.01596886       1.03857883       1.00022899       1.78188072       1.00065332       1.01380334       1.00115742 
        SGPT             SGOT          Alkphos 
  3.93498241       0.05616662      38.29760014
```

By running this command I could predict my data,

```
predict(mod_fit , newdata=testing)
```

But if I set `type="prob"` or `type="raw"`

```
predict(mod_fit , newdata=testing, type = "prob")
```

it falls in error:

> Error in dimnames(out) <- `*vtmp*` :
>
> length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent